# How to create a CacheRefreshPlan for a report with the PowerBI Server on prem API?

Tags: python, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-api

I manage to run a Report refresh from the API when the CacheRefreshPlan already exists.
But now i would like to create the CacheRefreshPlan if none exists for the report I want to refresh.
How is it possible to do this with the PowerBi Server on prem API ?

Here is my code:

```
data = """{
    "@odata.context": "https://myserver.com/ReportsPBI/api/v2.0/$metadata#CacheRefreshPlans",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": null,
            "Owner": null,
            "Description": "API created CacheRefreshPlan",
            "CatalogItemPath": "/path/reportname",
            "EventType": "DataModelRefresh",
            "ScheduleDescription": "At 2:00 AM on 11/21/2022",
            "LastRunTime": null,
            "LastStatus": null,
            "ModifiedBy": null,
            "ModifiedDate": "2022-11-21T16:04:48.187+01:00",
            "Schedule": {
                "ScheduleID": null,
                "Definition": {
                    "StartDateTime": "2022-11-21T02:00:00+01:00",
                    "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "EndDateSpecified": false,
                    "Recurrence": {
                        "MinuteRecurrence": null,
                        "DailyRecurrence": null,
                        "WeeklyRecurrence": null,
                        "MonthlyRecurrence": null,
                        "MonthlyDOWRecurrence": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "ParameterValues": []
        }
    ]
}"""

import requests, json

url = 'https://myserver.com/ReportsPBI/api/v2.0/CacheRefreshPlans'

s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
s.auth   = auth

headers = {'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
response = s.post(url, data= json.loads(data), headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response.status_code)
```

I run this and I have a 400 Bad Request  response.status_code to my post request.

Do you know what is missing, and/or what are the other steps to make it work ?

Which fields are mandatory or not ? A minimal json payload working example would be nice.
How to I generate an Id if needed ?

I found and read some docs , but did not found working examples and/or detailed enough for me:
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/PBIRS/2.0#/CacheRefreshPlans/AddCacheRefreshPlan